# Could you explain me one OOP confusion?

Tags: class, oop, object

I am creating a program for testing a website. Site has a registration process, which I am testing.

I have created a class named "Client", which should store the information about the client (name, family name, e-mail etc.).

Since I am testing, I use random number generator to generate a name for the client (I have the list of names, one of which is chosen randomly).

Obviously, I should create a method "generateName ()".

But the question is: in which class I should create it?

Lots of programmers would create the method in the Client class. And would do something like that:

```
client = new Client ();
client.generateName ();
```

But I have read, that this approach is incorrect - because the client does not generate name for himself. Program does.

Based on that information, I do as follows:

```
class Program
{
    private void generateName ();
}
...
class Client 
{
...
    public void name ( String name )
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

program = new Program ();
program.launch();

client = new Client ();
client.name ( program.generateName () );
```

But as I know, this approach is not used by the developers.

Could you clarify, how to know "what is right and what is wrong" here? And what information source should I use as an arbitrary for the cases of this kind?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `generateName()` could be a static method in `Client`, since it's independent of instances:

```
class Client {
    private String name;

    public Client(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static String generateRandomName() {
        String generatedName = ...;

        return generatedName;
    }
}
```

You could the simply pass it's value to the Client object as you currently are, or via the constructor:

```
client = new Client(Client.generateRandomName());
```

Otherwise, I'd suggest a ClientNameGenerator to handle name generation, to keep inline with [SRP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and to raise [cohesion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)). This would be the better choice, seeing how you may be needing more name generation methods in the future:

```
class ClientNameGenerator {
    public String generateRandomName() {
        String generatedName = ...;
        return generatedName;
    }

    //other name generation methods...
}
```

You can now use a `ClientNameGenerator` object to manage the generation of client names:

```
ClientNameGenerator nameGenerator = new ClientNameGenerator();

client = new Client(nameGenerator.generateRandomName());
```

Anytime you need to generate a name, simply use the `ClientNameGenerator` object you created.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of places which might be appropriate locations for this functionality.

You could have it as a private method on the Client class, used by a static factory method for generating Clients with a random name.

```
public class Client {
    ....

    public static Client randomlyNamed() {
        return new Client(randomName());
    }

    private static String randomName() {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

But that private method might be better extracted to a more appropriate class for generating random Strings...

```
public class Client {
    private static final int defaultNameLength = 8;
    ....

    public static Client randomlyNamed() {
        return new Client(Strings.randomString(defaultNameLength));
    }
}

public class Strings
    private static String randomString(int length) {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

You could then expand the static method into a general purpose ClientBuilder class, with an instance method named something like 'withRandomName()'.

```
public class Client {
    ...
}

public class ClientBuilder {
    private static final int defaultNameLength = 8;
    ...

    public ClientBuilder randomlyNamed() {
        this.name = Strings.randomString(defaultNameLength);
    }

    public Client build() {
        return new Client(name);
    }
}

public class Strings
    private static String randomString(int length) {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

An alternative would be an implementation of a NamingStrategy (e.g. ``) object which is given to a ClientBuilder object.

```
public class RandomNames implements NamingStrategy {
    private static final int defaultNameLength = 8;
    public String name() {
        return String.randomString(defaultNameLength);
    }
}


public class ClientBuilder {
    private final NamingStrategy nameSource;
    public ClientBuilder(NamingStrategy nameSource) {
        this.nameSource = nameSource;
    }

    public Client build() {
        return new Client(nameSource.name());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The pure way to go would be to have a separate class ClientGenerator that produces clients. Because generating clients is not typical client behavior and in your application model a client is no more than a passive data container for client properties. However, generating clients is an activity in "the client domain". Therefor it would be defendable to create a static method Client.NewClient(), like the .NET feamework does with Guid. On the other hand, a guid's very nature is to be generated, it does not represent something in the real world. It IS a spawnable id. So the comparison may not be all that ligitimate.

A common similar mistake (or impurity if you wish) is a Save method on an object. Instead one should have a Persister class that does the job. Or a Manager. Because Save is something you can do to or with the class, not behavior of the class ifself.